# Toshiba Recovery Error remd.exe

Tags: windows-10

Recently purchased a used Toshiba C55 series laptop. It has been wiped. Ordered a recovery flash drive from Toshiba, but it will not continue to load. Here is the response I receive after choosing the boot drive:

> remd.exe application error the instruction at 0x00007FF68F309B9C
>   referenced memory at 0x0000000000000000
>   the memory could not be read
>   Click ok to terminate the program

I am lost at this point.
Any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on below url, I hope it helps,

http://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/instruction-at-referenced-memory-could-not-be-read/

It has various ways as follows:-

Method 1 – Increase Virtual Memory

Method 2 – Uninstall Buggy Software

Method 3 – Update drivers and install latest patches

Method 4 – Perform a System Restore

Method 5 – Run System File Checker

Method 6 – Disable Add-ons in Internet browser

Method 7 – Uninstall old version of Java Runtime